# How can I restart my interval on click

Tags: javascript

How can I restart my interval on click? Here is my code is set to stop at 600 but what I want to do is when on click I want the interval time to restart. Here is the code:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 600){
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    $("#ReloadPage").load(location.href+" #ReloadPage>*","");
}, 500);
```

How can I restart my interval on click?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and on which ever click handler invoke the function again?

Comment: Just call this `startTime = new Date().getTime();` on click.

Comment: I tried starting my interval that way but its not starting